# mongodb mongorestore no --collection

Tags: mongodb, restore

I can't see any parameter that takes collection name.

Thier tutorial at
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongorestore/ suggested me to use

```
mongorestore --collection people --db accounts dump/accounts/
```

but it causes error. when I drop `--collection`, everything goes fine.

Now what will you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mongorestore` man page says the option is now `-c` or `--c` instead of `--collection`.